# Find angle to projected point on axis and angle to projected point

Tags: geometry

I am working on a robotics project and all i have to do is to make  a 3 wheeled robot to detect a tag (chessboard pattern for example) with it's camera, go to it, and stops facing it exactly, that means the `X axis of the camera` should be `parallel` to the `Tag's X' axis`, also the `distance` between the `center of the camera` and the `X' axis of the tag` should be `0`. all I have is the `Qauternions` and the position in 3d of the target (tag) and the camera of the robot is the origin (carrier of the cartesian coordinate system).

[Graphical explanation of the Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8gRj.jpg)

I figured out `alpha` by calculating the angle between `X` and `X'` but in some cases the rotation direction is misleading for the robot, here is an example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YZlr.jpg)

Also the distance from the projected point is always wrong, this is how I am calculating it: I calculate the line `l` that passes from the point `(xt , yt)` of the target and makes an angle `alpha` with `X'` vector and then I calculate the disatnce between the origin `(0,0)` and the line `l`, unfortunately it is wrong in most of the cases.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, 
Looking forward for your help.

Comment: First of all, why do you mention the quaternions? This seems to be a purely two dimensional motion planning in the plane. Instead of the quaternions, the complex numbers would do just fine (if necessary at all). Anyway, they are the two dimensional version of the quaternions ond are a subset (a subalfebra) of the latter. Am I right that this is 2D? Are the z axes of both the robot and the target always parallel?

Comment: @Futurologist 1- yes it is a 2 dimensional problem but the detection algorithm always gives the position and orientation in 3d anyway and i just use only the values that i need. 2- not in the initial position but at the end of the algorithm they should be parallel

Comment: So what is the data that you have (the input data)? Are you given the coordinates of the $X'$ vector with respect to the robots coordinate system? Do you know the position of the plane in which the motion occurs in the coordinate system of the robot? How is that plane represented? Are both the vector $X$ of the robot and vector $X'$ of the target always parallel to the plane in which the motion takes place? What abut the vectors $Y$ and $Z$ as well as $Y'$ and $Z'$?

Comment: @Futurologist 1-yes 2-yes 3- it is represented by  the X and Z vectors 4-yes they are parallel to the same plane (the motion plane) 5-Z should be parallel to Z' also at the end of the algorithm, I think Y and Y' are not important since it is just a 2d motion

Comment: Ah, so the plane is spanned by $X$ and $Z$, while $Y$ is perpendicular to the plane. The same with the target's coordinate frame $X', Y', Z'$ Is that right?

Comment: @Futurologist yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the coordinate system of the robot is $X, Y, Z$ where the vectors are of unit length and orthogonal to each other. $R$ is the point of the robot, to which the coordinate system is attached. Assume your vector $X'$ is given by coordinates $(u,v)$, i.e. 
$$X' = u \, X + v \, Z$$ and that the location of the tag is at point $T$. Your goal is to execute motion that takes vector $X$ to vector $-X' = -u\, X - v\, Z$ and vector $Z$ to vector $Z' = v\, X - u \, Z$. So simply take the dot product $\big(X\cdot (- X')\big) = - (X \cdot X') = \cos(\alpha)$, assuming that $X
$ is unit length, i.e. $|X'|^2 = (X' \cdot X') = 1$. If not, then take 
$$\frac{\big(X\cdot (-X')\big)}{\sqrt{(X'\cdot X')}} = - \frac{\big(X\cdot (u\, X + v\,Z)\big)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}} =  - \frac{u \big(X\cdot X\big) + v\big(X\cdot Z\big)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}} =  - \frac{u \big(X\cdot X\big)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}= \frac{- u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}$$ because $\big(X\cdot Z\big) = 0$ due to the orthogonality between vector $X$ and $Z$, and $\big(X\cdot X\big) = 1$ because $X$ is the unit vector from the orthonormal frame of the robot. Then $$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{- u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}$$ To determine the angle, however, you want to take $$\alpha = \text{arccos}\left(\frac{- u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}\right)$$ which gives angles only between $[0,\pi]$. You, however, may want angles between $[-\pi,\pi]$ or equivalently between $[0,2\pi]$. Then the sign of a second dot product
$$\sin(\alpha) = \frac{\big(Z\cdot(- X')\big)}{\sqrt{(X'\cdot X')}} = - \frac{\big(Z\cdot (u\, X + v\,Z)\big)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}} = - \frac{u \big(Z\cdot X\big) + v\big(Z\cdot Z\big)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}} = - \frac{v \big(Z\cdot Z\big)}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}= \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}$$ Thus the sign of the angle $\alpha$ should be $\text{sign}(\sin(\alpha)) = - \frac{v}{|v|}$ So finally, your angle should be 
$$\alpha = -\frac{v}{|v|} \text{arccos}\left(\frac{-u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}\right)$$

I am a bit in a hurry, so one may need to double check the signs.

From what I understand, you basically want the robot to first turn in a direction orthogonal to direction $X'$, move straight along the direction determined by the vector $Z'$ orthogonal to the vector $X'$ until it hits the line determined by the tag point $T$ and the vector $X'$, then turn nighty degrees and then go in the direction parallel to the vector $X'$ straight down to the tag. Am I right?

Then first, you have to calculate how far the the robot has to go perpendicularly to $X'$ to hit the line determined by $T$ and $X'$. Let the coordinates of $T$ in the frame of the robot be $(t_1,t_2)$, i.e. $T = t_1 \, X + t_2 \, Z$. The equation of the line  determined by $T$ and $X'$ can be written as $$v(x - t_1) - u(z - t_2) = 0$$ where $x,z$ denote coordinates in the plane. The robot has to go first along the line determined by a vector orthogonal to $X'$, which is $Z' = v \, X - u\, Z$. Then the trajectory along $Z'$ should be $sZ' = sv \, X - su \, Z$ and  $s$ should be chosen so that $sZ'$ actually lies on the line determined by $T$ and $X'$. In other words, $s$ satisfies the equation
$$v(sv - t_1) - u(-su - t_2) = 0$$ which transforms to 
$$sv^2 - t_1v + su^2 + t_2u = 0$$ Solving for $s$ leads to
$$s = \frac{t_1 v - t_2 u}{u^2 + v^2}$$ Finally, the oriented distance between the point $R$ of the robot and the point $P$ on the line determined by $T$ and $X'$ is
$$d = \text{sign}(s) |sZ'| = \text{sign}(s) |s|\, |Z'| = s \sqrt{u^2 + v^2} = \frac{t_1 v - t_2 u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}$$

So to guide the robot to the tag, the way you want, you have to decide that positively oriented rotation should be a counter-clockwise rotation (when looking at the plane from above), while negatively oriented should be clockwise rotation. Then, provided the vector $X' = u\, X + v\, Z$, calculate the oriented distance $$d = \frac{t_1 v - t_2 u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}$$ and the angle $$\alpha =  -\frac{v}{|v|} \text{arccos}\left(\frac{-u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}}\right)$$ Then make the robot turn of angle $\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha$ so that it is ready to travel in the  direction determined by vector $Z' \perp X'$ and if $d>0$ let the robot travel forward distance $d$ (if $d<0$ the robot has to go backwards), then let it stop, make it turn $90^{\circ}$ clockwise facing the tag and then let it go down to the tag along the direction $-X'$. If $d<0$ the robot has to go backwards after turning initially. The case when $v=0$ should be handled separately I think.

Comment: Thank you, So what about the distance between the robot and the projected point p shown in the illustration, and do you think that method could solve the problem that i am facing in the example that i provided ?

Comment: because the robot has to turn pi/2 - |alpha| in the opposite direction of alpha and  then goes a distance d to the projected point to reach the axis of the tag and then do a pi/2 in the other direction to face the tag. the problem in the example is the robot will go far from the tag and then turn and find nothing.